# Question amout mtownsend/request-xml (XML to array) plugin

Tags: php, arrays, xml, laravel, plugins

Have a question about mtownsend/request-xml  (XML to array) plugin.
So, plugin makes XML file to array.
I use it in my Laravel projects and there is several reason, because I need exact it, but here is one problem.

Have two simple XML files

first file `oneitem.xml` with one item `<flat>` into `<post>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <post>
        <flat>
            <roms>4</roms>
            <baths>2</baths>
        </flat>
    </post>
</data>
```

second file `severalitems.xml` one with several items `<flat>` into `<post>`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <post>
        <flat>
            <roms>4</roms>
            <baths>2</baths>
        </flat>
        <flat>
            <roms>5</roms>
            <baths>1</baths>
        </flat>
        <flat>
            <roms>7</roms>
            <baths>3</baths>
        </flat>
    </post>
</data>
```

Then, I use a simple code to make an array from this files, and show the result array for each:

```
$xmlone = XmlToArray::convert(file_get_contents('public/xml/test/oneitem.xml'));
$oneflat = $xmlone['post'];
print_r($oneflat);

$xmlseveral = XmlToArray::convert(file_get_contents('public/xml/test/severalitems.xml'));
$severalflats = $xmlseveral['post'];
print_r($severalflats);
```

If we try to make an array from first file (with one `flat`), and find all we have in `posts` we have this result:

`Array ( [flat] => Array ( [roms] => 4 [baths] => 2 ) )`

If we do the same in second file (with several `flat), we have this result

`Array ( [flat] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [roms] => 4 [baths] => 2 ) [1] => Array ( [roms] => 5 [baths] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [roms] => 7 [baths] => 3 ) )`

So, if we have several items, plugin adds a additional arrays with keys, [0], [1], [2]....
I need to do it the same, even there is just one item flat into posts. So the results have same formats.

I know, that it makes plugin. If plugin see, that there is just one flat in post, he makes result array simple.

The code of main file of plugin is here, but I cant understand, which lines do it...

Thanks for your help

```
public static function convert($xml, $outputRoot = false)
    {
        $array = self::xmlStringToArray($xml);
        if (!$outputRoot && array_key_exists('@root', $array)) {
            unset($array['@root']);
        }
        return $array;
    }

    protected static function xmlStringToArray($xmlstr)
    {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        $doc->loadXML($xmlstr);
        $root = $doc->documentElement;
        $output = self::domNodeToArray($root);
        $output['@root'] = $root->tagName;
        return $output;
    }

    protected static function domNodeToArray($node)
    {
        $output = [];
        switch ($node->nodeType) {
            case XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE:
            case XML_TEXT_NODE:
                $output = trim($node->textContent);
                break;
            case XML_ELEMENT_NODE:
                for ($i = 0, $m = $node->childNodes->length; $i < $m; $i++) {
                    $child = $node->childNodes->item($i);
                    $v = self::domNodeToArray($child);
                    if (isset($child->tagName)) {
                        $t = $child->tagName;
                        if (!isset($output[$t])) {
                            $output[$t] = [];
                        }
                        $output[$t][] = $v;
                    } elseif ($v || $v === '0') {
                        $output = (string) $v;
                    }
                }
                if ($node->attributes->length && !is_array($output)) { // Has attributes but isn't an array
                    $output = ['@content' => $output]; // Change output into an array.

                }
                if (is_array($output)) {
                    if ($node->attributes->length) {
                        $a = [];
                        foreach ($node->attributes as $attrName => $attrNode) {
                            $a[$attrName] = (string) $attrNode->value;


                        }
                        $output['@attributes'] = $a;

                    }
                    foreach ($output as $t => $v) {

                        if (is_array($v) && count($v) == 1 && $t != '@attributes') {
                            $output[$t] = $v[0];
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        return $output;
    }
}
```

** Thanks for your help!**

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its not possible. As I understood, standard PHP tools to XML to array conversion makes it so. The plugin based on them.

Anyway, I think there is a way to solve it through changing source code of this plugin, but I solved in my situation, by working with results of XML to array conversion, and check if result array have one `flat` or several.